# Should I add a custom section to app.config? If so, how?

Tags: c#, app-config, configuration-files

I have a program that periodically polls a certain folder for log files.  When it finds a log file, it reads it, does whatever it has to, and moves on.  The program that writes the log files keeps appending, not overwriting, so I store a last modified date and a bookmark line, which is wherever I got up to last time I read the file.  All good so far.

Now, I want to persist my bookmark info, so that if I shut down the polling app and restart it, it doesn't start again at the beginning of every log file.  I don't want to hassle about storing the info in the DB; a simple XML file will do.  So I thought about storing the info in the `app.config` file.

First question is, is this a Wrong Thing To Do?  Is `app.config` meant only to be read from, not written to at runtime?  In which case, the logical answer would be simply to write a separate xml file?

Second, if it's OK to do this: I found a nice blog post about [how to make a custom config section](http://jopinblog.wordpress.com/2007/04/20/custom-configurationsections-in-net-20-config-files/), but it seems to screw up other parts of the app that try to read the config file using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(key)`, with a `ConfigurationErrorsException`, message = "Configuration system failed to initialize".  What to do about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd store this as a separate file from the app.config - it doesn't seem like configuration data to me. You could use Xml Serialization, Yaml, Json, or even (please, god, no) binary serialization, and either store it alongside the exe (if you have write permissions there) or somewhere from the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

[ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) is the easiest way to do this. I am using this but here is one issue. You must know what type is the value:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MyPropertyOne" value="Hello" />
    <add key="MyPropertyTwo" value="2" />
  </appSettings> 
</configuration>

string propertyOne = (string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyPropertyOne"];
int propertyTwo = (int)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyPropertyTwo"];
```

But you write your own [a complex custom configuration section](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37776/Writing-a-complex-custom-configuration-section)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would recommend using a custom section - that gives you the flexibility to have a structure that makes sense for you. The built-in `<appSettings>` are a) strings only, and b) just "flat" list of a bunch of keys (and their values).

You should check out Jon Rista's three-part series on .NET 2.0 configuration up on CodeProject.

- [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
- [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
- [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Highly recommended, well written and extremely helpful! Jon shows very nicely how to build your own custom config section, and how to represent that in code.

And as jgauffin already mentioned - there's also the [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com/) tool to help you get your stuff done quickly (but it sure helps to *understand* what the CSD is doing - so invest the time, read Jon's three articles, then use CSD).

Answer (score 1):

custom sections are a wonderful tool! dont use appSettings for serious apps.

Here is code for custom section
IN WEB.CONFIG

```
<configuration> 
  <configSections>
    <section name="Misc" type="Config"/>    <<-- this registers a custom section called Misc
    <Misc configSource="config_misc.config"/> <<-- this says to look for for it in file "config_misc.config"
    (...)
```

Then create a file CONFIG_MISC.CONFIG  the root of your website and put in it

```
<Misc 
    MySetting1="true" 
 />
```

THEN IN your webapp, in APP_CODE folder, create a class like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Specialized; 


public class Config : ConfigurationSection
{
    private static string _CONFIG_SECTION = "Misc";

    #region singleton implementation
    private static Config _config;
    static Config()
    {
        _config = (Config)ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig(_CONFIG_SECTION);
    }
    #endregion 

    public static bool MySetting1
    {
        get
        {
            return _config._MySetting1;
        }
    }

    #region public properties the define the config items we are looking for
    [ConfigurationProperty("MySetting1", IsRequired = false)]
    public bool _MySetting1
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this["MySetting1"];
        }
    }        
    #endregion
}
```

This code is a copy of my code so while cutting, i may have made a mistake but it should get you started.

You now have a wonderfuly simple way of reaching your setting simply via Config.MySetting1

breaking up your settings to more .config files also has lots of benefits, especially for maintenance and modularity

Answer (score 0):

Use [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com/)